# Using Bootstrap Responsiveness for Page Framed in Silverlight

Tags: html, silverlight, twitter-bootstrap, telerik, asp.net-mvc-5

I am embedding an HTML5 page into my Silverlight project using Telerik's RadHtmlPlaceholder.  The HTML5 page was generated by an MVC5 project that uses Bootstrap. But Bootstrap's responsiveness feature does not work when the page is in embedded.  Are there any changes I can make to the source project or the RadHtmlPlaceholder to take advantage of Bootstrap's responsiveness?